# Avoiding PostBack in asp

Tags: asp.net, web, postback

I want to avoid postback when my button event fired. Due to postback my List gets empty again. Kindly Help me out with this. What should i do to avoid postback. I am using ASP button.

Here is my button method

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());


                venues.Add(id);

                foreach (int item1 in venues)
                {



                    if (!hashset.Add(item1))
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Duplicate Items');</script>");
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        foreach (var items in venues)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Venues where VenueID = '" + items + "'";
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            ds.Fill(dt);
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                                Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
                                Picture = dr["Picture"].ToString();
                                Price = dr["Price"].ToString();
                            }
                            con.Close();
                            if (Request.Cookies["aa"] == null)
                            {
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Name.ToString() + "," + Address.ToString() + "," + Picture.ToString() + "," + Price.ToString();
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Request.Cookies["aa"].Value + "|" + Name.ToString() + "," + Address.ToString() + "," + Picture.ToString() + "," + Price.ToString();
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how ASP.NET works. Your list doesn't empty because of the post back. Your list is empty because the previous page request is completed. You have to fill your list on every page load whether that's the initial load or because of a postback.

Comment: And you're going to have to edit your question to include the relevant code. e.g. Where does the list initially get populated?

Comment: @ColinMackay i have added my code. can you help me out ?

Comment: Where is your list defined? I assume it is `venues` you are talking about, your description is rather vague. Can you include the method signature? What populates `venues` to begin with?

Comment: List as well as hashset is defined above the method.  im trying to restrict user from selecting duplicate elements for shopping. I am populating my @ColinMackay list with the ids of the venue. then im transferring them to the hashset just to make sure that no duplicate id is present. then i am fetching the data from database and inserting it into cookies. Every thing is going fine except this issue. On every click my list get refreshed and empty. I am not sure why

Comment: and yes venues is my list.